# VB.net databinding linq

Tags: .net, linq, data-binding

can someone explain why databinding to textbox2 works but not for textbox1?

Using a BindingSource as Datasource, but using the query directly does also not work.

```
Private Class DTO1
        Public Property id As Integer        
        Public Property value As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Public Property value2 As String
    End Class

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim lst As New List(Of DTO1)
        Dim a As New DTO1
        a.id = 1
        Dim o As Object = 1
        a.value = o
        lst.Add(a)

        a = New DTO1
        a.id = 2
        a.value = Nothing
        lst.Add(a)

        bs.DataSource = (From p In lst Select p).ToList
        grd.DataSource = bs
        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", grd.DataSource, "value")
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("text", grd.DataSource, "value2")
    End Sub
```

every time i move out from textbox1 the initial value is displayed againe.
_tia
rene

edit: got this working. when using nullable values you have to pass in some more parameters ...

```
Me.DataBindings.Add(pr_PropertyName, pr_Datasource, pr_Datamember, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing)
```

did the trick

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as such so that it gets marked as answered (and removed from the list of unanswered questions): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 0):

just to have this question answered ...

```
.DataBindings.Add(pr_PropertyName, pr_Datasource, pr_Datamember, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing)
```